# Get server names in a column and check if they exist in AD

Tags: powershell

I have a script that shows reserved IP list with computer names like below:

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ScopeId 192.168.2.0 |
  Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation |
  select IPAddress, ScopeId, addressstate, clientid, Name
```

The output of above code is like below:

```
IPAddress     ScopeId      addressstate         clientid           Name
---------     -------      ------------         --------           ----
192.168.2.57  192.168.2.0  InactiveReservation  00-50-56-9a-44-01  xyz.domain.com
192.168.2.58  192.168.2.0  InactiveReservation  00-50-56-9a-44-03  abc.domain.com
```

What I want is to get server names in `Name` column and to check if each of which exists in AD or not. I need to write the output of existence check in a column next to `Name`.

How can I manage this?

Comment: Thanks but when I add this code, I got the same output as before. This does not help.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks for help. Only problem is I can not get other columns (ScopeId, IPaddress, clientID etc.) when I add the code you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for adding derivative information:

```
... | select ..., Name, @{n='Exists';e={$name=$_.Name; [bool](Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -eq '$name'")}}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.